# Google Maps iOS SDK: Map not loading although it's enabled and the key is correct

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I am facing an issue with google maps on iOS swift,

I searched a lot and found many solutions for the issue, that is not working with me :)

which mainly focuses on ensuring that you have:

1- enabled Google maps API for ios,

2- and adding the correct API key

I made sure that i have dont both solution but till now the map is not loading, 
and giving me a blank page like below image

Using Swift 3

[image]

Comment: Did you set iOS app restriction on the API key? Do you have active billing account that is now mandatory?

Comment: No i didn't add restrictions, i guess the billing is the issue. i didn't add an active billing.
I will try it out and write the answer here

Comment: Didn't work although i added an active billing

Comment: iOS app restriction is also required. Check the documentation. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key#detailed_guide_for_users_of_the_standard

Comment: I added restrictions, but not working till now

Comment: Any suggestions i can't find any solution

Comment: Do you have the same bundleID (your app == google console)?

Comment: yes it's the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the issue,

I added pod 'GoogleMaps/M4B' to my pods, since it was declared it's a must for businesses (Premium plan) in Google maps get started guide.

When I removed it everything worked fine.

Although I tried both Premium plan and free API keys previously.